# Matlab header files

Tags: matlab, header-files

I have some part of code that is repeated in a number of matlab funcions (.m files). I want to put the code into functions that can be defined in a single file (say CommandHelper.m) and use these functions in my original .m files. (just as defined in header files). Is this possible?

Comment: You can put these functions into separate m-files, name them the same as the function defined within, make sure they are in the same directory as your "main" m file and call these functions just like any other function in matlab. Would that serve your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB comes with a full featured object model as documented in [Object-Oriented Programming](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/ug_intropage.html). You may provide your helper functions as static methods.

```
classdef CommandHelper   
    methods (Static)
        function text = firstCommand()
           text = 'firstCommand'; 
        end

        function text = secondCommand()
           text = 'secondCommand'; 
        end
    end       
end
```

Helper functions may be called from the command line or any other function, script with the following syntax.

```
>> CommandHelper.firstCommand

ans = firstCommand

>> CommandHelper.secondCommand

ans = secondCommand
```